# ORDER BY acting wrong (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

So my problem is the following: I get a list of items out of a MySQL database, and I want to sort it with Javascript after that (It can be edited dynamically). The main problem are numbers and characters. Assuming this is the list in the database:

`3, a, 2, 1, b`

The statement would return:

`a, b, 1, 2, 3`

But I want it to be:

`1, 2, 3, a, b`

My database is `utf8_unicode_ci`, but that doesn't help. It still produces the wrong result. (I can't just check if they are numbers and then sort them to the top because an item could also be named "2some56thing" and has to be before "asome56thing").

Comment: Can you post an example of your query and JS?

Comment: write a [custom sort method](https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort(function(a, b) {
    // Stuff to get the text out of the DOM
    return textb > texta;
}
```

You will need to return -1 (or any number < 0) from your [custom compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) if `texta` is greater than `textb`, otherwise the sort won't work (and maybe not sort at all). Better:

```
    return textb>=texta ? textb>texta ? 1 : 0 : -1;
```

or

```
    return textb>texta - texta>textb;
```

or

```
    return texta.localeCompare(textb);
```

Comment: I worked quite well for now, but I updated all my sort functions, thanks. I already searched for hours what the function had to return, but I forgot to check the MDN...

Answer (score 0):

This link might help, I suppose:
http://matthewturland.com/2008/11/05/natural-ordering-in-mysql/

Try this:

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(`name`, `login`)+0, CONCAT(`name`, `login`)
```

Answer (score 0):

what locale settings do you have in mysql?

my sorting gets this output:

```
SELECT * FROM sorting ORDER BY a;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| a    |
| b    |
+------+
```

Comment: Strange. The problem is that the script has to run on many different systems, regardless of the settings. Is there a possibility to set it at runtime?

Comment: It throws an error: "COLLATION 'latin2_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'", no matter what collation I used. So obviously, I am restricted to the latin1 collations. Ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I am an idiot. I altered the whole database to utf8_unicode_ci now. But the result is still the same, what are you using?

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name = 'sorting'\G` => `Collation: utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 0):

Don't just use the `>` operator.

Since you're implementing your own sort function, you can be as complex as you like.

First, detect if `texta` and `textb` are of the same type, if not, indicate that numeric comes before string (using 1 or -1, depending on which variable is the numeric one).

If they're of the same type, you can use `>`, but that's not really appropriate; comparison operators should return a numeric value, not a boolean.

Thus:

```
 (a == b) ? 0 : ( (a < b) ? -1 : 1 )
```